# Unknown .exe file

Tags: windows-7

I downloaded a program called glasswire to see which programs are using the internet.
One program doesn't show in task manager and I can't find out what it does. Does someone know what it is or how I can find it out?

**Info about the program:**
name: gwinstst.exe
traffic type: HTTP
Host: 199.7.51.72
incoming: 3.4kb
outgoing: 0.447kb
location: c:\users\thijs\appdata\local\temp\nsx8a46.tmp\gwinstst.exe

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No idea what the exe does, but for me it connected to some server in the domain of "akamaitechnologies.com", which appears to be some "internet content delivery" company.

The question that is remaining is where gwinstst.exe is from - I was wondering if it's not actually a temporary executable from the glasswire people to check for updates or something similar, since I also only saw this through glasswire?

Answer (score 3):

The fact that this file is in the Appdata\Temp area to me is a big red flag that it's suspect.  I'd try uploading it to VirusTotal - but also be prepared to do a full virus scan on your machine.

Comment: I don't think it's a red flag, "just because" it's a temporary directory - try searching for *.exe in this directory, you'll probably find a few executables from all kinds of parent applications (including some Google Update services).

Answer (score 3):

**@GlassWireLabs** Twitter account confirmed that `gwinstst.exe` is their own application. In their words:

> "Yes it is ours.  It lets us know how many installs we get per day."

Source: https://twitter.com/GlassWireLabs/status/504363540074221568

(They also confirmed they will be rewriting their FAQ/Privacy Policy pages to reflect more detail in what they collect and why.)